# Can't figure out seg fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, switch-statement, getopt, getopt-long

Why do I keep getting a set fault when I try and pass -H in the command line as a flag? -h (help) is working perfectly but -H(header) messes up every single time.

I have a main function as well which calls parse_command_line by passing the argc & argc.

the bool is defined as bool header = false;

the file is char** file = NULL;

and the reason I have the file+=1; in the code is so that it compiles because I am using a makefile that changes all warnings into errors.

```
#include "parse.h"              /* prototypes for exported functions */
#include "../main/unused.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int
parse_command_line (int argc, char **argv, bool *header, char **file)
{
int oc = 0;
file += 1;
bool help = false;
struct option long_options[] = 
{
    {"header", no_argument, NULL, 'H'},
    {"help", no_argument, NULL, 'h'},
    {0, 0, 0, 0}
};

while ((oc = getopt_long(argc, argv, "+Hh", long_options, NULL)) != -1)
{
    printf("The value of oc = %d\n", oc);

    switch(oc)
    {
        case 'h':
            help = true;
            break;
        case 'H':
            printf("inside case H");
            *header = true;
            break;
        case '?':
            fprintf(stderr, "Unknown flag = -%c, type -h or --help for help!\n", optopt);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

printf("Out of loop");    if (optind+1 != argc)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Uh oh, invalid input! Try again with -h or --help for help!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (help)
{
    printf("\nHaving some trouble? Let me show you the ropes!\n\n");
    printf("Format: ydi <option(s)> mini-elf-file\n\n");
    printf("Here's your options:\n");
    printf("-h --help       Display usage\n");
    printf("-H --header     Show the Mini-Elf header\n");
    exit(1);
}

if (header)
{
    printf("Inside HEader");
    FILE *file;
    uint16_t nums[6];
    file = fopen(argv[optind], "r");

    #define STRUCT_ITEMS 7
    fread(nums, 16, 6, file);
    int cur_print;
    for (cur_print = 0; cur_print < STRUCT_ITEMS; cur_print++)
    {
        printf("%d ", nums[cur_print]);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

My parse.h file is as follows:

```
#ifndef __PARSE_COMMAND_LINE__
#define __PARSE_COMMAND_LINE__
#include <stdbool.h>

int parse_command_line (int argc, char **argv, bool *header, char **file);

#endif
```

There are other files such as elf.h and elf.c which I have not implemented and are not called at all at this point, which leads me to believe they are not going to be the problem and don't need to post the small 2 line files. My main function is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>              /* standard I/O */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "unused.h"             /* UNUSED macro */
#include "../cmdline/parse.h"   /* command line parser */
#include "../y86/elf.h"         /* Mini-ELF format */

int
main (int argc UNUSED, char **argv UNUSED)
{
  printf ("Congratulations, you have compiled your source code!\n");
  bool header = false;
  char **file = NULL;
  parse_command_line (argc, argv, &header, file);
  return 0;
}
```

And the file unused.h (because the compiler will make unused variables an error instead of warning) is as follows:

```
#ifndef __UNUSED__
#define __UNUSED__
#define UNUSED __attribute__ ((unused))
#endif
```

Comment: Where's the rest of the code? and from a wild guess, I'd say change `*header` to `header`.

Comment: @Mike unfortunately I get this error: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror], I added the rest of the code though

Comment: What happens if you declare oc as a char instead of an int and cast the result of getopt_long as a char?

Comment: @Mike It's still seg faulting (core dumped)

Comment: I still think it has something to do with `*header` because you're modifying data stored at the address of `header` which could be outside of the allowable memory space for your program.

Comment: posted code is still not complete.  Please post code that:  1) cleanly compiles, 2) minimal size program 3) that still shows the problem.  The statement the OP made that they did post the rest of the function seems to not be true

Comment: How do you expect us to debug your code when key items/files are missing, like `parse.h` and `../main/unused.h`

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans,  please indent consistently.   I.E. indent after every opening brace '{'.   un-indent before every closing brace '}' (never use tabs to indent) Suggest using 4 spaces for each level of indent as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.   please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: @user3629249 My apologizes, my first time on stack overflow and I wasn't sure how much could would be appropriate, I'll edit it right now

Comment: in C, `true`, `false`, and `bool` are defined in the `stdbool.h` header file, so need to insert statement: `#include <stdbool.h>`

Comment: @user3629249 okay, I added it to main and parse.c. I'm still getting a seg fault sadly

Comment: Have you run your program in a debugger? That will probably help you find the problem in less time than it takes for all these posts to SO. And it's an essential skill to hone in any case.

Comment: @kaylum yes I've tried a debugger and still trying it but am having trouble using it which is why I've posted here

Comment: Well, then you can tell us exactly which line of code the seg fault occurs on. Your debugger gives you that information.

Comment: There are quite a few errors in your code. The segfault is possibly caused by this: `for (cur_print = 0; cur_print < STRUCT_ITEMS; cur_print++) printf("%d ", nums[cur_print]);`. `nums` only has 6 elements in it. But `STRUCT_ITEMS` is 7. This overflowing `nums`. Also `if (header)` should be `if (*header)`;

Comment: Note that debug printing lines must end with a newline; they won't appear in a timely fashion otherwise — meaning you may not see multiple lots of `printf()` output that were produced before the actual crash site, leading to erroneous conclusions about where the crash occurs.  Running under a debugger also helps, of course.

Comment: Also, note that symbols starting with double underscore, or underscore and a capital letter, are unconditionally reserved for the implementation.  Yes, system headers use names with double underscores — they're part of the implementation and aren't allowed to pollute your namespace.  You shouldn't pollute their namespace.  For all practical purposes, and multiple counter-examples notwithstanding, treat names starting with underscore as reserved for the implementation.

Comment: the `main()` function is using the argc and argv parameters, so the 'ununsed' macro should not be used on those parameters

Comment: in function: `main()`, these two lines: `char **file = NULL;
  parse_command_line (argc, argv, &header, file);` will result in undefined behaviour and perhaps a seg fault.  the correct lines would be: `char *file = NULL;
  parse_command_line (argc, argv, &header, &file);`

Comment: looking at the revised code: this string: "+Hh" should be more like: "+H:h" and the long_options[] first entry needs to be modified to expect the file name argument and where to set the pointer to the filename. Then the case 'H': needs to include setting the **file pointer parameter. the line: file += 1; needs to be removed. the #include "../main/unused.h" statement needs to be removed

Comment: in the function: `parse_command_line()` for the few parameters, you might be much better off to simply index through the argv[] array to drive the actions

Comment: Why has the OP deleted the question? It has one negative, but nobody had marked it for "close". Now, all the comments and the given answer is of no use for anybody :(  Can any power user undelete it?

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't check the return value of fopen, which will be NULL in case of an error.  Dereferencing NULL in the fread call causes a segfault.

Comment: This is certainly a plausible explanation, especially since the debug printing doesn't end outputs with newlines.